# Mockito test case for JDBC template insert query

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, mockito

I have the following insert query:

```
public String index() {
    this.getJdbcTemplate().execute("insert into COUNTRY(COUNTRY_CD,COUNTRY_NAME)values('TN','TIRUNELVELI')");
```

How do I write a mockito test case for this?

Comment: To write a test for something, you should first define the expected behaviour, so please do so

Comment: You should know that we can't just "generate" tests based on a piece of code. You have to tell us what your expectations are when this method is executed. Do you want to make sure that the `execute()` function is properly called? Do you want to make sure that a record is inserted into the database? ... Without that, we can only make assumptions, so you should clarify what exactly you want to test in your question.

Comment: yes this datas are inserted into SQL server database

Comment: I am new to spring boot and mockito testing I have written insert method to insert some data into to the sql server database I am able insert this data.I need to  check this method is executing properly without using database